# JNI - How to modify a parameter when calling a Java method from C++?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a Java method something like this

```
public boolean ReadBool(String ValueName, Boolean Value)  
{  
  boolean Retval = ...;  
  ...  
  Value = true;  
  ...  
  return bRetval;  
}
```

that I call from native code (C++) like this:

```
jMethodID MethodId = pEnv->GetMethodID(ClassId, "ReadBool", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Boolean;)Z");  
// What goes instead of "??" ?  
bool bOk = pEnv->CallBooleanMethod(myobject, MethodId, pEnv->NewStringUTF("Value1"), "??");
```

My intention is for the Java method to "return" a boolean value in Value. I understand that a built-in boolean will not work for this purpose. Is it possible to do this with a Boolean wrapper? How does one construct the object to pass in place of "??" ?

I have googled around, but some questions remain. For example, I suppose I could pass an object created by calling Boolean's <init> "method". But wouldn't the assignment in the Java ReadBool make Value refer to a newly created wrapper, throwing away that first object? In that case I would have called <init> for nothing. I think it should be possible to create (in the native code) something that Java sees as an object that is null and whose type is Boolean. Is that possible? Or am I on the wrong track altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Booleans are immutable in Java, so you need your own wrapper class, which can be really simple though:

```
public class BooleanWrapper {
    public boolean val;
    // public is fine here imo, but you can obviously use [g|s]etters as well
}
```

Or if you don't want this, we can use a.. well not really pretty, but nice to know hack:

```
public void hack(boolean[] vals) {
    vals[0] = true; // voila, now you change the value itself
}
```

Has some obvious drawbacks when calling (and looks strange), but if you're fine with keeping a specific parameter sequence, you can do:

```
public void hack(boolean.. vals) {
    vals[0] = true; // voila, now you change the value itself
}
```

that way the caller doesn't have to use stuff like `new boolean[] {}`;

You can obviously cheat and change the internal state of the Boolean object itself, but that will have unwanted consequences (booleans are cached ergo if you change the Boolean.TRUE instance to false internally this will give interesting results). So don't do that.

Comment: Booleans are immutable - does that mean when a Boolean is passed as parameter, the method can't change it? I imagined Value (the parameter to ReadBool) was a reference, and that the assignment in ReadBool would contruct a new Boolean and then Value would then refer to that. It that not the case? (Sorry for asking such basic stuff, but I'm new to Java ;-)

Comment: Yes, your interpretation of immutable is correct.  It is preferred to always use immutable classes (wherever possible anyway) and use return values for results.  If you have multiple return values that are related then create an object for them--if you have multiple return values that are not related then make your method more specific.

Comment: It's true; I verified it as follows: void TestCall(Boolean b) { b = false; } and then called Boolean bTest = true; TestCall(bTest); The value of b is actually modified in TestCall, and I understand a new Boolean is being created which b then refers to. But how come bTest is still true - don't b and bTest refer to the same Boolean?

Comment: Everything in Java is passed by value - just search for one of the ca. 300 questions on SO (that question is asked at least once a month it seems) if you have questions about that :)

Comment: Well, yes, the *reference* to b is copied by value, so don't b and bTest refer to the same Boolean? So after assigning a new Boolean to b, why don't b and bTest have the same value?

Comment: Aah, I finally get it :-) A copy of the reference is passed to the method, and this reference is then modified to point elsewhere - while the original reference still points to what it used to. Not so easy for a C++ developer to get his head around it...

Comment: Yeah there's no exact same semantic in C/C++. You can think of it as pass by value with a copy constructor that returns the original object - umn I think that is waterproof ;)